# STM32U5 Alarm IT not clearing

Tags: stm32, interrupt, alarm, hal, real-time-clock

I have a problem with clearing the RTC alarm IT. I am using STM32U585 MCU and RTC alarms that are set to specific time. Date is masked, only time is used.
Here is the code to set up the alarm:

```
    sAlarm.Alarm = RTC_ALARM_A;
    sAlarm.AlarmDateWeekDay = RTC_WEEKDAY_MONDAY;
    sAlarm.AlarmDateWeekDaySel = RTC_ALARMDATEWEEKDAYSEL_WEEKDAY;
    sAlarm.AlarmMask = RTC_ALARMMASK_DATEWEEKDAY;
    sAlarm.AlarmSubSecondMask = RTC_ALARMSUBSECONDMASK_ALL;
    sAlarm.AlarmTime.DayLightSaving = RTC_DAYLIGHTSAVING_NONE;
    sAlarm.AlarmTime.StoreOperation = RTC_STOREOPERATION_RESET;
    sAlarm.AlarmTime.TimeFormat = RTC_HOURFORMAT_24;
    sAlarm.AlarmTime.Hours = (uint8_t)hours;
    sAlarm.AlarmTime.Minutes = (uint8_t)minutes;
    sAlarm.AlarmTime.Seconds = (uint8_t)seconds;
    sAlarm.AlarmTime.SubSeconds = RTC_ALARMSUBSECONDMASK_ALL;

    if (HAL_RTC_SetAlarm_IT(&hrtc, &sAlarm, RTC_FORMAT_BIN) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }
```

I am using this alarm mainly to wake up the MCU from shutdown. But if there is a situation where MCU is on and running, I need to know that the alarm tripped. For this I'am using `HAL_RTC_AlarmAEventCallback()` where I print some message to the console.

The problem is, that the message gets printed multiple times because `HAL_RTC_AlarmAEventCallback()` is called many times while while seconds in alarm and RTC seconds match.

Is there some way where I can clear the alarm without completly disabling alarm IT?

I mean, there have to be, because if I mask the seconds, the ISR will be called again and again till the hour advances and alarm hour registers will not match anymore with RTC.

I've alread tried to manually set the bit CALRAF in SCR to clear the ALARF in RTC->SR but this doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

As I figured out, HAL is trying to clear the alarm A flag, but fails to do so, because it did not enabled backup access beforehand.

I've solved my problem by manually clearing the flag in `HAL_RTC_AlarmAEventCallback()`

Here is the whole process:

```
HAL_PWR_EnableBkUpAccess();
WRITE_REG(RTC->SCR, RTC_SCR_CALRAF);
HAL_PWR_DisableBkUpAccess();
```

Hope this will help someone who is struggling with this :-).